# Implement noUiSlider in a view template - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, nouislider

I'm new to AngularJS.

I want a range slider(noUiSlider) on a Angular view.

I found these 2 libraries to achieve that:

1) https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-nouislider (Angular plugin)

2) https://github.com/Yankovsky/nouislider-angular (Angular plugin)

I chose option (2) and followed each steps exactly as mentioned there. But I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module fastrankApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
```

Any idea how to solve that? OR can anybody provide steps to implement  noUiSlider in AgularJS in detail?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

do u inject your uislider to your App(same for javascript code in your web footer)?. Btw. its look like that problem is somewhere else.
For slider I use classic Bootstrap Slider
What is your AngularJs version.
Share your code.

Comment: AngularJS: v1.4.5
Yes I have injected all necessary js into footer.
My code:
angular.module('fastrankApp', ['nouislider'])
  .controller('DomainsCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    $scope.values = [20, 70]
    $scope.options = {
        range: {min: 0, max: 100}
    }    
});